# Не видно билд в iTunes connect

Tags: xcode, apple

Не появляется билд в iTunes connect после загрузки его из xCode. Пробовал загружать отдельно через .ipa архив и с другого компьютера. Так-же удалял приложение в iTunes connect, и поменяв  bundle ID, заливал заново.

При загрузке того-же номера билда из xCode, загрузка говорила что данная сборка уже существует в iTunes connect, но ее там не видно.

Так-же пытался залить версию месячной давности, но все тщетно.

Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Appstore connect есть такой механизм, что когда на этапе анализа загруженного архива будут выявлены проблемы - эта сборка будет скрыта (поэтому вы не можете загрузить тот же билд), а на почту будет отправлено письмо с описанием проблем.

Просмотрите почту, исправьте проблемы, повысьте версию сборки и загрузите заново.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую